# WebClient.DownloadString() Not Producing Exact HTML

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webclient

So here's the deal. I'm creating a spider bot for a website that scans all the product pages and records the product data. I'm using C# and the WebClient library to download the HTML string. The site I'm crawling must be specially made because the HTML that is received from WebClient.DownloadString() is different than the HTML that I get when I view the source of the HTML when visiting it on a browser. This seems intentional because the only info I can't get is the price.

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem or can anyone explain what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: It would help if we could see what differences are coming up in the code.  For example, what does "view source" show you and what does your bot show you?

Comment: Can you provide the URL to the site in question?

Comment: Personally I'd use a `WebRequest` / `WebResponse` to retrieve the details.

Or use DownloadData and format the `byte[]` into a string using the proper encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably using the the user agent string to decide what content to send. The example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) shows how to set the user agent header.

Comment: OP here, I was able to find out exactly why. Apparently the website uses an AJAX function to get sensitive data. When I do a screen scrape with WebClient.DownloadString(), I get the HTML document, but instead of getting this sensitive info, I get a segment of AJAX where this should be. Does this help? I will post the code for the AJAX that is included in the HTML

Comment: <!-- AJAX Product Details Panel Begins -->
      <div id="product_details" style="position:relative"></div>
  <script language="javascript">
  var rQsp = 'productId=3519&isFlooring=true&displayAccessories=true&productVariantId=3080&isBuyable=true&stockMessage=&isLinearFt=false&isCanned=false&isStoreOnly=false&tabList=tab_acc_trim|tab_similarproducts|tab_specslist|tab_prod_desc|tab_reviews|tab_emailafriend&checkStoreInventory=false&useStoreId=0';
  showProductDetails(rQsp);
  </script>

Comment: The ajax call is being made by the function showProductDetails,you need to look at the source code of that function to find out how to scrape the data.

Comment: That function is not present in the html document

Comment: IT must be within a references javascript file.  Look for <script> tags and pulldown the .js file referenced by the src attribute.  It will be in one of them.