# WebClient.DownloadString seems to change some of the html from an external site

Tags: asp.net, html, webclient

I have an ASP.NET website (.aspx) that I call from within an ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile website (.cshtml) to get its html response string. Both sites are hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 system. They are created and published with VS2010 Professional.

-If I go directly to the external site and view source then it is correct.

-If I use any of the below ways of getting the external html:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
     {
         html = client.DownloadString(strUrl);
     }
```

or

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
     { 
        byte[] DataBuffer = client.DownloadData(strUrl);
        html = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(DataBuffer);
     }
```

or

```
WebResponse objResponse;
WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   html = sr.ReadToEnd();
   sr.Close();
}
```

then the html is changed from this ( where the font-family is set on a parent table ):

```
<td align="right" style="color:Red;background-color:White;width:4.375em;border-bottom:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;">-27.0%</td>
```

to this:

```
<td align="right" bgcolor="White" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;"><font face="Arial,sans-serif" color="Red">-27.0%</font></td>
```

I doesn't look like anything else has changed other than the font style is changed to a tag, the background color moved from a style to a tag attribute, and the width style being completely removed. This happens on the entire page.
If I put a break point on the html variable and view it then the html has already been changed by the time DownloadString is called.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
this link: [WebClient.DownloadString() Not Producing Exact HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877286/webclient-downloadstring-not-producing-exact-html?rq=1)
is not quite the same thing as I am not using Ajax or JavaScript on the external page.

edit:
here are the request headers from fiddler and the site that calls the other site (I used Chrome):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: .ASPXBrowserOverride=Mozilla%2f4.0+(compatible%3b+MSIE+6.0%3b+Windows+CE%3b+IEMobile+8.12%3b+MSIEMobile+6.0);
```

going to the site directly I get this request header:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: .ASPXBrowserOverride=Mozilla%2f4.0+(compatible%3b+MSIE+6.0%3b+Windows+CE%3b+IEMobile+8.12%3b+MSIEMobile+6.0);
```

edit:

If I look at the client object in debug mode client.Headers is empty before and after DownloadString is called.
Also, after DownloadString is called here are the client.ResponseHeaders:

```
{Content-Length: 267123
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 27 Nov 2012 18:37:27 GMT
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=******; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}
```

Solution:

Unfortunately I cannot accept two answers. Both Icarus and James Lawruk's answers helped me to solve the problem. I am picking an answer based on what most recently lead me to the final solution. So thanks to you both!

So here is the solution in a nutshell:

Use fiddler to view the request headers and find the user-agent.
Modify the code as follows:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
     {
         client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11");
         html = client.DownloadString(strUrl);
     }
```

Comment: [Browser sniffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing)

Comment: What type of site is it?  Windows vs Linux hosted?  What CMS? etc.

Comment: @James Lawruk - I update my question with that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the user-agent value and experiment with different browsers. This may prove the Web site is switching the HTML response based on the user-agent header.

```
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5");
var iphoneHtml = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.yoursite.com");
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11");
var safariHtml = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.yoursite.com");
```

Comment: Hey! doing that but setting it to the user-agent I found in fiddler seems to have fixed my problem..... "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"........ what does that mean? I think it might be a bad idea, for future proofing, to hard code the user-agent but I am not sure.

Comment: By default, Webclient does not send a user-agent header, so the Web site must have code to respond to that by sending different markup.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Browser Sniffing as Dour pointed out on his comment because `WebClient` does not change the resulting HTML at all.

You can probably verify this if you use Fiddler and set up the request headers in exactly the same way `WebClient` does. I bet you you get the same HTML output.

Comment: I posted the request headers from fiddler but they look same.

Comment: @Soenhay How could the UserAgent headers from `WebClient` have this: 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11" ? `WebClient` wouldn't add that header. Are you sure you are looking at the right headers sent by `WebClient`?

Comment: I am new to fiddler so I might be looking at the wrong thing... I just removed all sessions from fiddler then refreshed the web page so that one line is in fiddler. Then i clicked on it and that is what was under request headers.... If I do the same thing with the project running in debug mode there are several other lines in fiddler but they all have that same UserAgent.